# Locally Lipschitz does not imply $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$; let $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. If $S\subseteq A$, we say that $S$ satisfies the **Lipschitz condition** on $S$ if the function $\lambda(x,y)=|g(x)-g(y)|/|x-y|$ is bounded for $x\neq y\in S$. We say that $g$ is **locally Lipschitz** if each point of $A$ has a neighborhood on which $g$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition.

> Show that if $g$ is locally Lipschitz, then $g$ is not necessarily of class $C^1$.

I've thought about functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Functions like $f(x)=x^a$ for $a\geq 1$ are locally Lipschitz, but they're also continuously differentiable, so don't quite work.

Comment: Consider the integral of a bounded but not continuous function. A step function, maybe.

Comment: @leo That's not locally Lipschitz, I believe

Comment: True. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Mika H: Compute integral of a step-function and see if you can identify it with a familiar function. Then check that it is globally Lipschitz.

Comment: @studiosus I agree with Daniel Fischer's function (and voted it up). I was responding to leo's function, which he already deleted upon realizing that it is not locally Lipschitz :)

Comment: The absolute value function obviously works when $m=n=1.$ Can you think of something analogous to use when $m$ and $n$ are arbitrarily specified positive integers? (The norm function in $\mathbb R$ is $\dots).$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609765/is-a-lipschitz-function-differentiable/2609787#2609787

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Euclidean norm $f(x)=\|x\|$ is probably the simplest example: the Lipschitz condition  comes straight from the triangle inequality, and the non-differentiability is seen from the fact that the restriction of $f$ to the first coordinate  axis is $|x_1|$.

Answer (score 3):

By Rademacher's theorem   any Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable a.e.

The derivative
of a lipschitz function is a bounded measurable function, but this derivative need not be continuous.

Hence the locally lipschitz function   need not be $C^1$.

For example $f(x) = \frac {x^i x^j}{ |x|}  $ on the unit $n$-ball.

Comment: What does dividing by $|x|$ on the unit $n$-ball contribute to the example?  Isn't $|x|=1$ in that setting?

Comment: dividing by |x| give a singularity to show the derivative is not continuous. btw:  |x|=1 is only on the boundary of the ball.