# Is a Lipschitz function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

**Is a Lipschitz function differentiable?**

I have been wondering whether or not this property applies to all functions.

> I do not need a formal proof, just the concept behind it. 
>   Let $f: [a,b] \to [c,d]$ be a continuous function (What is more - it is uniformly continuous!) And let's assusme that it's also Lipschitz continuous on this interval.

Does this set of assumptions imply that $f$ is differentiable  on $(a,b)$?

Comment: It only implies it is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: "Let $f: [a,b] \to [c,d]$ be a continuous function (What is more - it is uniformly continuous!) And let's assusme that it's also Lipschitz continuous on this integral." You should be aware that these assumptions are highly redundant. Lipschitz implies all preceding assumptions

Comment: Lipschitz continuous does not imply differentiability. In fact, we can think of a function being Lipschitz continuous as being in between continuous and differentiable, since of course Lipschitz continuous implies continuous. If a function is differentiable then it will satisfy the mean value theorem, which is very similar to the condition to be Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is not always true  indeed, good counterexample could be $x\mapsto |x-a|$. But rather, we have

> **Theorem:** [Radamacher theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) says every Lipschitz function is almost everywhere differentiable

Fine a nice proof of this theorem here: [An Elementary Proof of Rademacher's Theorem - James Murphy](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiJ8pu3zuHYAhWNKlAKHRcLDskQFghAMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.intfxdx.com%2Fdownloads%2Frademacher-thm-2015.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1KhvqywM_tHERNbdYZVvyC) or [Here using distribution theory](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwiJ8pu3zuHYAhWNKlAKHRcLDskQFghcMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.arizona.edu%2F~friedlan%2Fteach%2F553%2Fradem.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Y60ixNID0CPKXftvfivUA)

Comment: those do not include a proof of the Rademacher theorem in dimension 1. Terrence Tao has a reasonably self-contained proof of this and a couple other related here:
 https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/#more-4290

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't think those proof exclude the one dimensional case. Or  am I wrong . one the proof use distributional derivative

Comment: Well I may have missed it but both links start with "in dimension one its because Lipschitz implies absolutely continuous/bounded variation so the result is true", which isn't wrong but I doubt someone who would ask this question on MSE would know this result for AC or BV functions

Comment: yes many proofs of Rademacher in R^n rely on the fact having been established on R. To prove it on R, one of the the underlying truths is that a continuous and increasing function is differentiable almost everywhere. In fact an increasing function is differentiable almost everywhere, but this isn't needed for Rademacher's theorem.

Answer (score 20):

The function
$$x \mapsto \left|x\right|$$
is Lipschitz-continuous (with $k=1$) but not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not imply $f$ is differentiable.

Try $f(x) = |x|$ as an example!